# How to get the long/lat information from a NodeID and vice versa

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, shortest-path

In the SpatiaLite website they explain how to use `.osm` data to create a SpatiaLite database, that contains a single table, where each row is an arc of the road graph. Then, they explain the procedure of calculating the shortest path from A to B in [their website](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/dijkstra.html):

1. Create the `VirtualNetwork` from a `.osm` file using a tool they provide
2. Execute the following query: `select * from VirtualNetwork where NodeFrom=267209305 and NoteTo=267209702` to get the shortest path
3. Below the result you are supposed to get from the query above. It represents every arc on the shortest path.

[image: 1]

Questions:

1. How to get the **Latitude/Longitude** from every **NodeID** that is on the shortest path. Otherwise, I will not be able to interpret what those **NodeIDs** mean.
2. How to get the **NodeIDs** from the **Latitude/Longitude** of `NodeFrom` and `NodeTo`. Otherwise, I will not be able to execute the shortest path query in the first place.

Comment: The tool spatialite_osm_net does not create a table for nodes, as stated on the website you refer to: 'simply because they can be indirectly retrieved starting from the corresponding arcs'. That means that you have to create a new table for nodes with columns for NodeID and coordinates. Then you fill this table with `node_from` and the coordinates of the first vertex of `geometry`. Which commands to use depends on the software you are going to use. Can you describe that in your question?

Comment: @Detlev That makes sense, however since you commented on this question, if you want take a look at my other [very relevant question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54966/dijkstras-algorithm-on-huge-graphs) that I can't figure out. I am not using any software at the moment, I am simply in the planning phase. Can you elaborate on what `geometry` is ? I can't figure out what that even means. `BLOB sz=272 GEOMETRY`. I find it very difficult to read through the documentation. It seems to be a little all over the place.

Comment: @Detlev To fill the table shouldn't I simply go over every node in the .osm file ? I am not sure I understand what you mean't with your comment.

Comment: Yes, this be the best idea, if NodeIds haven't changed - better then mine. What I meant was to use `select NodeFrom, AsText(StartPoint(Geometry)) from VirtualNetwork`, which should return the first vertex of the linestring saved in column Geometry. Column Geometry has the road segments as list of points, usually entered in WKT format, e.g. LINESTRING(x0 y0, x1 y1, ..., xn yn).

Comment: @Detlev  How many points would it return ? 18 ? This should be faster than just querying a separate table. Right ? Why would I made a separate table then. If that works, then the only thing I am missing is getting the `NodeID` of A and B from the `lat/lon` information so that I can run the Dijkstra's algorithm. Is there any way to get that without me making a separate table by myself ?

Comment: `StartPoint()` return only one point and `AsText()` converts it into text, eg. `POINT(22.255163 42.341812)`. With `ST_X(StartPoint(geom))` or `ST_Y()` respectively you get the x and y coordinate. So it should be possible to use this in the WHERE condition of a query: NodeFrom where StartPoint() eq something, and NodeTo where EndPoint() eq sth. But might be a matter of performance, since all rows must be visited.

Comment: @Detlev This should be what I need. Also how can I get the NodeID from lat/long of the nodes A and B, so that I can run the A->B shortest path algorithm ? Feel free to post the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If shortest path calculation on the VirtualNetwork returns a set as shown in your question, then column geometry in the first row contains the geometry of the shortest path as line string.

An expression like

```
AsText(Geometry)
```

returns the line string, that is a list of point coordinates, in human readable WKT format.

```
LINESTRING(x0 y0, x1 y1, ..., xn yn)
```

If you need the coordinate for a given NodeId (e.g. NodeFrom as in the shortest path result set), you need to query the underlying real road network (the imported OSM data) alike:

```
SELECT ST_X(StartPoint(geometry)), ST_Y(StartPoint(geometry))
    FROM the_road_network
    WHERE the_road_network.node_from = NodeFrom
```

With ST_X(StartPoint(geom)) or ST_Y() respectively you get the longitude and latitude of the first point of polyline geometry.

Otherwise if you have the coordinates of a node and are looking for the NodeId without building a database table for nodes:

```
SELECT node_from
    FROM the_road_network
    WHERE ST_X(StartPoint(geometry)) = longitude
    AND ST_Y(StartPoint(geometry)) = latitude
```

and `node_to` and `EndPoint(geometry)` respectively.

If you do not have the exact coordinate of a node, but are looking for the nearest node to a given coordinate, use a query like this:

```
-- nearest from_node to point (21.25, 42.15)
SELECT node_from, 
       MIN(ST_DISTANCE(Startpoint(geometry), ST_POINT(21.25, 42.15)))
    FROM the_road_network
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, what I actually would need is not to get the NodeID from coordinates, but get the `closest` NodeID from coordinates. So I don't think that the equals `=` will do the trick. Do you have any idea how that can be done with the SpatiaLite API ?

Comment: See the edit answer. Minimizing ST_DISTANCE should be what you are looking for.